# Dataframe shift: why does axis have no effect?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-03', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': rng.day}, index=rng) # Val in practice is exogenous data
df.index.name = 'Date'
```

produces the following DataFrame:

```
Date        Val 
2017-01-03  3
2017-01-04  4
2017-01-05  5
2017-01-06  6
2017-01-07  7
```

I want to shift the DataFrame using a time offset.  But I'm discovering the `axis` argument to `.shift()` has no effect.  Both of the following calls:

```
df.shift(2, 'D', axis=0)
df.shift(2, 'D', axis=1)
```

produce this same result (namely: the *index* is shifted by 2 days):

```
Date        Val
2017-01-05  3
2017-01-06  4
2017-01-07  5
2017-01-08  6
2017-01-09  7
```

Why does the `axis` argument have no effect?  I would expect that when `axis=1` the index (Date) values would stay constant and the *Val* column would be shifted.

Comment: Please read the docs on [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html); this scenario is mentioned in the "Notes" section.

Comment: @root: "If freq is specified then the index values are shifted but the data is not realigned. That is, use freq if you would like to extend the index when shifting and preserve the original data."  I'm not certain what this means.  Does it mean that we cannot shift the columns when using an offset?  I.e., the `axis` argument has no effect when the `freq` argument is used?  If you can parse that note with certainty then please post as an answer.

Comment: That is my interpretation.  If you have a fixed frequency index (e.g. as in your example it's daily) then you can just specify the number: `df.shift(2)`.  If this is not the case, it's not entirely clear what the expected behavior for a `shift` should be, and seems like it could result in something that isn't actually a shift, depending on the logic you actually want to use.